# Inserting an array of 16-bit ints to MySQL, from C

Tags: mysql, c

I have a large array of int16_t that I need to put into a MySQL database.  I have constructed a query string by copying the values to a char buffer, but in the end it doesn't work (char is 1 byte, int16_t is two bytes.)  The documentation I've found online about inserting arrays to MySQL does so with character arrays.

How can I insert this array of int16_t to a MySQL database?

Comment: Don't copy into a "char buffer", create a query *string*. A string containing lots of `UPDATE` or `INSERT` SQL statements.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - But isn't it a bad idea to loop and UPDATE thousands of times just to insert one row into a database?  I am working with real-time data..

Comment: you cannot insert rows with `UPDATE`, thats impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look at the BLOB datatype. which can store binary blocks of data into a column. There are 4 different flavors, according to the size you need. Have a look at the following example, where images are stored in the database:

http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlc/

The really interesting part is about 80% down in the page, where an image is stored and later retrieved from the database. Take particular care about the 
mysql_real_escape_string() function, which makes sure that the data will be legal for the actual query. You should be able to send the int16 array immediately.

Edit... Here is the 'save' routing which works. It saves the ints array
as a binary blob into the database. This program is NOT complete. Eg. it doesn't connect to the database,

```
#define SIZE 20000
int16_t ints[SIZE];

MYSQL *con;

int
ints_saved(void) // Returns 0 if there's an error
{
  char   *chunk, *st, *query;
  size_t ints_size = sizeof(ints), 
         st_len;
  int qlen;

  chunk = (char *)malloc(ints_size*2 + 1);
  // template for creating SQL
  st = "insert into Ints(Id, Data) values(1, '%s')"; 
  st_len = strlen(st);

  // Remove dangerous characters
  mysql_real_escape_string(con, chunk, (char *)ints, ints_size);

  query = (char *)malloc(st_len + 2*ints_size+1);
  // Construct the actual query here
  qlen = snprintf(query, st_len + 2*ints_size+1, st, chunk);

  printf("%s\n", query);
  // Execute the query
  if (mysql_real_query(con, query, qlen)) {
    printf("%s\n", mysql_error(con));
    return(0);
  };

  return(1);
}
```

Note that the database table was defined with two columns, Id(int), and Data(blob). You may have to modify blob, if you have other size requirements.

Warning: Nobody cried out yet, but do take care that this system might produce different results in different compilers. Some compilers may align 16-bit ints to 4-byte boundaries. So, though I have taken this into account with the sizeof() function, the actually saved record might occupy more space on some machines. If you want to avoid the problem, you can avoid this with 'packed' records - see the docs for your compiler.

The **write** process: The int16_t's are in an array. If I look at it as integers, I get:

17767     9158   -26519    18547    -9135    23807   -27574    22764     7977    31949    22714   -10325 
   16882     7931   -22045    -7866      124    25282     2132    10232     8987    -5656   -12825    17293

Looking at the same array as bytes (or characters), I see:

```
67 45 C6 23 69 98 73 48 51 DC FF 5C 4A 94 EC 58 29 1F CD 7C BA 58 AB D7
```

(The 67 45 is the first int value, 17767)

I can't write this, as byte 11 is 0x5C, which confuses the query string:

```
67 45 C6 23 69 98 73 48 51 DC FF 5C 4A 94 EC 58 29 1F CD 7C BA 58 AB D7  
                                 ^^
```

So, I call the mysql_escape function, and use the result to form the query:

```
67 45 c6 23 69 98 73 48 51 dc ff 5c 5c 4a 94 ec 58 29 1f cd 7c ba 58 ab 
                                 ^^^^^
```

Notice the extra 0x5c?

When I execute the query, I send the escaped string to MySQL, and MySQL *immediately* removes the escapes and writes the UN-ESCAPED string to the database. So, from now on, where are no more extra 0x5c characters. If you read it back, the the data is 'pure' again.

A really minimalist example. Say I want to write just one 0x5c to a table:

I can't write: `insert into Ints(Id, Data) values (1, '\')` because MySQL would think I'm escaping the ' after the \. (remember the '\' is the 0x5c)

So I escape that \: `insert into Ints(Id, Data) values (1, '\\')`. When MySQL receives this query, it inserts only *one* \ though.

In the table only one character is inserted. And when read back, it produces only one character.

Comment: I am storing the binary data in a blob.  It's getting from the program to the mysql database that is the problem (e.g. how to use insert or update with this array of int16_t elements.)

Comment: Edited the answer above to include actual - working - code which does what you want, from the indications in the link I gave you before.

Comment: I have been using the same source, but thanks for working it to where I can send it at an array of int16_ts.  I have the same problem with this solution that I had with the character solution however: mysql_real_escape_string leaves 5c (\) characters throughout the database input.  Would you know why?

Comment: Yes... 0x5c is the escape character (NOT the ASCII ESC character, but the backslash). If you check the next character in the escaped qyery, you'll find 'dangerous' characters, such as the backslash itself. That's ok though. The data actually written to the record does not have these 0x5c's. They are just so that the query gets safely to MySQL.

Comment: Yep, but they end up getting inserted into the BLOB.  I don't know why my binary data is any different than a picture or other binary file...

Comment: How do you know the escapes are in the blob? The 0x5c could be valid integer values. I did a test with the 20000 values, and assigned random values to all ints. The resulting blob, when seen with phpMyAdmin (in reality, saved as a binary file from MyAdmin, as it doesn't have a viewer for blobs), was *exactly* 40000 bytes long - so no extra bytes. How do you read the data? And which engine do you use? (I used InnoDB) And what is the value of the next byte(s)?

Comment: I wrote to file and DB at the same time to help troubleshoot.  The DB data matches until a stray 5c shows up, then everything gets off kilter... and that happens pretty frequently.  Also in the DB data, 5c precedes 0x00 or another special character.

Comment: Can you share that code? "The DB data matches" you say, but exactly how do you read from the database. And you don't call the mysql_real_escape_string() function on reading do you? That would be incorrect.

Comment: http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlc/ -- there's their code.  They insert it with mysql_real_escape_string() (which apparently just prepares the string for transport, not storage in the db), and the retrieve the image without trying to get rid of any extra (e.g. backslash) characters.

Comment: Again, on read, there is nothing to get rid of. The data in the database does NOT contain any escapes. It CAN contain backslashes, of course, but then these backslashes are part of the original data.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I'm still working on this issue but have made some progress.